# Access Table Corrupting database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table, “tblData_Dir_Statistics_Detail” with 15 fields that is holding about 150,000 records.  I can load the records into this table but, am having trouble updating other tables from this table (I want to use several different queries to update a couple different tables).  There is only one index on the table and the only thing unusual about the table is there are 3 text fields that I run out to 255 characters because some of the paths\data are that long or even exceed 255.  I have tried trim these to 150 characters but it has no impact on the correcting the problems that I am having using this table.
Additionally, I manually recreated the table because it acts like it is corrupted.  Even this had no impact on the problems.
The original problem that I was getting is that my code would stop with a “System resource exceeded.”.
Here is the list of things I am experience and can’t seem to figure out why:

1. When I use the table in an update query (using task manager) I always see my Physical Memory usage for Access jump from about 35,000 K to 85,000 K instantly when the code hits this query and then, within a second or two, I get the resources exceed error.
2. Sometimes, but not all the time, when I compact and repair,  tblData_Dir_Statistics_Detail is deleted by the process and is subsequently listed in  MSysCompactError table as an error.  The “ErrorCode” in the table is -1011 and the “ErrorDiscription” is “System resource exceeded.”
   [image]
3. Sometimes, but not all the time, when I compact and repair, if I lose tblData_Dir_Statistics_Detail, I will lose the next one below it in the database window (shows also in the SYS table).
4. Sometimes, but not all the time, when I compact and repair, if I lose tblData_Dir_Statistics_Detail, I will lose the next TWO positions below it in the database window (shows also in the SYS table).

I have used table structures like this with much larger tables without problems for years.  Additionally, I have a parallel table “tblData_Dir_Statistics” which has virtually the same structure and holds the same data but at a summarized level, and have no trouble with that or any other table.

Summary:
My suspicion is that there is some kind of character being imported into one of the fields that is corrupting this entire table.

1. If this is true, how could I find the corruption?
2. If it is not this, what else could it be?

Many Thanks!

Comment: What version of Access are you running, and what is the file format version?

Comment: @ Gord Thompson Access 2007 and 2007

Answer (score 1):

A few considerations:

- Access files have a size-limit of 2 GB. If your file becomes at any time bigger than 2 GB (even by 1 byte) the whole file is corrupted
- Access creates temporary objects when sorting data and/or executing queries (and those temporary objects are created and stored in the file). Depending on the complexity of your queries, those temporary objects might be pushing the file size up (see previous paragraph).
- If you are using text fields with lengths bigger than 255 characters, consider using Memo fields (these fields cannot be indexed as far as I remember, so be careful when using them)
- Consider adding more indexes to your tables to ease and speed up the queries.
- Consider dividing the database: Put all the data in one (or more) file(s) and link the tables in it (them) to another Access file, and execute the queries in this last one.

Comment: • Process starts at 250 K and grows to 1.1 Gig.  No Size barrier here. 
• Queries are very simple with only one link to the table being updated
• I’ve tried all sort of indexes the ID field
• I’ve tried all sort of indexes the ID field and the error is instantaneous, the moment, the instant that the code hits the query (you can see the Memory usage sore (in task manager) and the exceed resource message pop up).
• The only size constraint that I believe I am hitting is the “RAM outage” when I hit the query containing the table

Comment: Another test that I did was to run a simple Select query on that table (no other table linked), just before the problem query hits the problem table (stopping the code just prior) and the select query “exceeds the resources”.  This same select query runs fine if I stop the code and then close and open the database.  ?!?!?!

Comment: @T-Rex I would consider using other RDBMS if possible; OpenOffice or LibreOffice Base are similar to Access... but maybe you should consider something bigger, like MySQL or PostgreSQL (you can link databases in MySQL/PostgreSQL using ODBC). I consider Access a good learning tool and a good small project platform, but for bigger, real life, scenarios, it fails sometimes (I've been there before, and that's why I stopped using Access).

Comment: @T-Rex, you say the Process starts at 250K and grows to 1.1 Gig. Is that memory usage or file size. File size is what Barranka was referring to. Are you by any chance running this across a wireless network or WAN? Access should not be used across either, especially compact/repair. Resources exceeded, is usually inaccurate with Access, it seems to be something that it throws out when it doesn't know what else to do. Another issue to look for is the record size. A record may not be larger than 2k. If your update is causing the record size to be exceeded, that would cause problems.

Comment: @AVG I had forgotten about the row size! (gee, I haven't used Access in a while!) One more reason to use something bigger and better ;)

Comment: @ Baranka 1st - Client constraint is to use Access. I find data issues to be a pain no matter what I am using.
@AVG My error exactly coincides with the RAM Spike as Access RAM usage goes from 35K to  85K in a split second and the overall system RAM jumps from 60% to 85%.  I can close down other APPs an it will run to completion.
 Baranka 2nd - The number of rows is about 1,500,000.  I have used 10 times this row size in other databases with larger number of fields (65 (vs 15) fields and more).  I still think it is some kind of corrupt data.

Comment: @T-Rex Row size is NOT the number of rows, which is not an issue. It is the number of bytes that a single row totals to. E.G. a long integer takes up 4 bytes, whether it is null or not. A text field (255 or less) takes up 2 or 4 (I forget) bytes, plus the number of bytes of its contained data. A memo field is stored in a separate page and only takes up a few bytes in the main record as a pointer to the actual data. You haven't addressed the very important questions on file size and whether you are working over a wireless network or WAN. Also, 85K RAM is nothing.

Comment: @ AVG - It is a network connection at work and the 85K pushes total ram to 85% (when accumlated with other programs in progress) (40% of my RAM is gone before I even open access) 
I am going to switch them to memo fields to see if that alleviates the concern. Thanks

Comment: @T-Rex I have to insist: *What about the file size?* Also, using Access over a network is very prone to errors (I know that for a fact: some years ago I had to deal with numerous problems of data corruption using an Access database over a LAN). Consider using replication

Comment: @Baranka - The Database itself is about 512,764 KB  before processing / update begins.
The Database bloats to about 1,100,000 Kb after processing / update ends
The “core database table” holds 1,356,000 records and is “squeezed” into the “table in question” at a summary level for statistics about the core table.
The table in question has about 155,000 records in it.
The query in question is updating (not appending) from the table in questions, to another, more summarized table with about 90,000 records in it.